# How to duplicate an existing Cognito form

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to duplicate an existing Cognito form? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that just as soon as I've asked the question I managed to find the answer as well. Selecting "new form" button displays an option copy an existing form. That allowed me to copy the form easily. It works within the organization but not between tow different organizations. That's a shame. Hopefully that functionality will come in the future.

Comment: Yes, we are looking into ways to share forms between organizations!  I am glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Is the form copy available between organizations? Or different accounts?